# IOUtils.toString taking to long

Tags: java, json, inputstream, httpserver

I have this class which opens a HTTP-Server and listens on a port. The reply is a http-header plus a json object. The class takes the input stream from the server, converts it to a string, filters the http header and parses the json object.

The thing is that the conversion from input stream to string is taking about 3 seconds. Is there a way to read the inputstream faster?

```
public class GamestateListener {

private static int PORT = 3001; // Port specified in your cfg
public static ServerSocket listenServer;
private static JSONObject MYJSONOBJ;

public GamestateListener() {
    try {
        listenServer = new ServerSocket(PORT); // open new Server Socket
        System.out.println("Started Socket..."); // printing out started
                                                    // listening
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public JSONObject listenAndParseJSON() throws IOException {

    System.out
            .println("Listening for connection on port " + PORT + " ...."); // printing
                                                                            // out
                                                                            // started
                                                                            // listening

    try (Socket socket = listenServer.accept()) { // wait for connection

        System.out.println("Start get From Socket           "
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        InputStream mis = socket.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Stop get From Socket           "
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        String responseString = IOUtils.toString(mis, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Stop to String           "
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        MYJSONOBJ = new JSONObject(responseString.substring(responseString
                .indexOf("{")));// split the response string

        return MYJSONOBJ;// return the json obj

    } catch (Exception e) {
        MYJSONOBJ = new JSONObject("{ERROR:True}");// create error obj
        return MYJSONOBJ;// return it
    }

}

}
```

Comment: how large is the json object?

Comment: have you checked, how fast the data is actually sent to the server?

Comment: Your impl does not measure the toString conversion I think. It measures the time it takes to READ the inputstream and convert it. So I think the 3 seconds are related to your network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not measuring what you think you are. Here:

```
System.out.println("Start get From Socket           "
        + System.currentTimeMillis());
InputStream mis = socket.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Stop get From Socket           "
        + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

... you seem to think that you've read all the data when `getInputStream()` returns. You haven't. You've just got a stream you can read from. It means there's a connection, but that's all.

If you want to measure how long it takes *just to read all the data* (and not actually process it) you could do something like:

```
System.out.println("Start get From Socket           "
        + System.currentTimeMillis());
InputStream mis = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
// Read all the data (but ignore it)
while ((mis.read(buffer)) != -1) ;
System.out.println("Stop get From Socket           "
        + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Of course, there then won't be any data to read for the rest of the code, but you'll see how long *just the data reading* takes. My guess is that that'll be about 3 seconds... which could be due to slow networking, or the client taking a long time to even *send* all the data. (It could connect, sleep for 2.9 seconds and *then* send a bunch of data.)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. The client is the csgo gamestate integration.
There are already a few python scripts which use it and they seem to be able to react much faster to the events happening.
https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Game_State_Integration

Comment: @Trojan: Well we can't really tell - but the first thing you should do is try using the diagnostic change I provided above. Then you'll be able to tell what the `IOUtils.toString` overhead is beyond the time required to just read the data.

Comment: The output is:
Start get From Socket           1455040519365
Stop get From Socket           1455040524356
So it is simliar to the old one.

Comment: @Trojan: Right, that's about 5 seconds. So this basically isn't `IOUtils.toString` by the looks of it. You need to look at why the client is taking so long to post the data (and how much data it's posting).